# Loop selection if Vertices have less or more then 4 faces

Tags: loop

[Link to this video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NayT9.png)

How Blender Guru selected Loops with vertex which has five contiguous faces. When I try to select Loop with vertex which has more or less four vertex Loop selection are breaking on this Vertex
[image]

---

[image]
Okay, but what is a difference in my case, why here I can't select all Loops, it breaks right in vertex which has five faces.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it selects the edge all around and by underneath, if you cut an edge on the bottom you'll see that it won't work any more.

[image]

Comment: Okay, but what is a difference in my case, why here I can't select all Loops, it breaks right in vertex which has five faces. Look image below

Comment: because if your object is symmetrical it is stopped on the other side: here it can't continue because it meets 5 faces, if on the other side it also meets 5 faces it can't continue either, in my object it can because it is not stopped all around then it makes the joint between the 2 vertices because when you select 2 vertices the edge between them is automatically selected

Comment: Huge thanks, I understood at last!